# created filter authorization but it doesn't work

Tags: postman, codeigniter-4

i created a filter authorization. when i want to login using token to access the home menu but i have a problem. when I access the home menu without using the token it still works. I am attaching a screenshot from my postman to access the home menu without a bearer token and to access the home menu using a bearer token.

this source code, Auth.php

```php
namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\Key;
use Config\Services;

class Auth implements FilterInterface
{
    /**
     * Do whatever processing this filter needs to do.
     * By default it should not return anything during
     * normal execution. However, when an abnormal state
     * is found, it should return an instance of
     * CodeIgniter\HTTP\Response. If it does, script
     * execution will end and that Response will be
     * sent back to the client, allowing for error pages,
     * redirects, etc.
     *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param array|null       $arguments
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        $key = getenv('TOKEN_SECRET');
        $header = $request->getServer('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION');
        if (!$header) return Services::response()
                            ->setJSON(['msg' => 'Token Required'])
                            ->setStatusCode(ResponseInterface::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        
        $token = explode(' ', $header)[1];

        try {
            JWT::decode($token, new Key($key, 'HS256'));
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return Services::response()
                            ->setJSON(['msg' => 'Token tidak valid'])
                            ->setStatusCode(ResponseInterface::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Allows After filters to inspect and modify the response
     * object as needed. This method does not allow any way
     * to stop execution of other after filters, short of
     * throwing an Exception or Error.
     *
     * @param RequestInterface  $request
     * @param ResponseInterface $response
     * @param array|null        $arguments
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    
}
```

do friends here have a solution to overcome this problem?

[without using bearer token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB8Uy.png) [using bearer token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEDpY.png)

Comment: How are these filters implemented in routes?

Comment: $routes->get('/home', 'Home::index', ['filter' => 'auth']);
$routes->resource('internal');
$routes->post('register', 'Register::index');
$routes->post('login', 'Login::index');

Comment: And is it registered in Config/Filters ? Can you include that code as well.

Comment: Hey @LussyIka could you solve it in any way?